# Uses of "that" as relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> 1. Peter invited the boy in his birthday party that was new in the class.
> 2. Peter invited his birthday party the boy that was new in the class.

If I use that as relative clause the sentences above are correct? Or there is any different way to make such sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Peter invited to his birthday party the boy who|that was new in the
>   class.
>
> Peter invited the boy who|that was new in the class to his birthday party.

You can use **who** or **that**.

Answer (score 0):

> Peter invited the boy **who** was new in the class **to** his birthday party.

Peter [Subject] invited [Verb] the boy [Object] who was new in class [Further specification].

The polite (and IMHO most correct) way to refer to people is to use "who" instead of "that" (which you would use to refer to a thing.)

For a thing (or animal), you can use `that` or `which`.

> I saw a car that was bright red.
>
> The only pants which looked good on me were too short.

Comment: Fbitterlich  then I could speak like  . I did  not check in  my computer the email that you sent from you computer.

Comment: I [=subject] did not check [=verb] the email [object] that you sent from your computer [=further specification]. But yes, this use of "that" is correct. You can also use "which" instead ("... which you sent ...".)

Comment: My concern is in My sentence, " in my computer" is indirect object which is placed after verb [=I did not check in my computer the email that you sent  from your computer.  The full sentence is correct grameticaly

Answer (score 0):

> Dave is one of our salesmen. He spoke to our customer, Susan.
>
> Dave is the salesman *who/that* spoke to Susan.
>
> Susan is one of our customers. Dave spoke to her.
>
> Susan is the customer Dave spoke to.  (no need in English to use who or that)

You can't use *that* in **extra-information clauses**:

Dave spoke to Susan, **who** is our customer.

Dave, **who** is our salesman, spoke to Susan.

Therefore:

> He's the boy. He's new in the class.
>
> Peter invited the boy who/that is new in the class to his party.

Or, as extra information about the boy:

> Peter invited the boy, who is new in the class, to his party.